# Dynamic parameters with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm developing a search app with `angular` using `ui-router`.

**Requirements:**

- The search form has too many fields and all have to be optional.
- Users should share with another users the URL that display the page with the result list. (So I need to use querystring)

So I could have urls like

```
path/to/url/list?p=123&v=876

path/to/url/list?c=yes&a=true&p=123

path/to/url/list?z=yes&c=yes&a=true&p=123

path/to/url/list?z=yes&v=876&a=true&p=123
```

And endless combinations. I know that I can use $location.search() to get all params in json format. That is great! but the question is How can I define the url state with `ui-router`? Define explicitly all params in the url is not an option. I have read many post but I didn't find a concrete answers.

Comment: Defined one parameter - query. Put into it all params.

Comment: How can I pass all search params in just one parameter? encode params in base64 could be a reasonable option?

Comment: if you're getting parameters from `$location` you don't need to define them in state

Comment: @AlekseyL. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting parameters from `$location` you don't need to define them in state explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best way is to use 'resolve' property of $stateProvider configuration:

```
$stateProvider.state('mystate', {
  // Some code here
  resolve: {
     queryData: ['$location', ($location) => {
       $location.absUrl(); // Contains your full URI
       return true;
     }]
  }
});
```

It's kind of initialization. After that, ui-router will cut URI, but you will store needed data. This case also works fine, when user passing URI directly in browser address input.

Also you can try to set $urlRouterProvider with $urlMatcher for this purposes, but it will be more difficult.